# sjp.frq - different colors for bars in r

Tags: r, colors, sjplot

I am preparing series of plots, using sjPlot package. For simple frequencies presentation I use sjp.frq. I would like to use different colors for each bar. I found the option to choose color but it works only for whole series: the switch geom.colors allows to change the color of all bars. Even the combination geom.colors=c("color1","color2","color3") doesn't work.

Is there any solution to achieve something similar to this: 
[image]

```
data(mpg)

sjp.frq(mpg$year,title = "", axis.title = "", 
        show.prc = TRUE, show.n = FALSE,
        show.axis.values = FALSE)
```

Comment: Please place your photo in your post properly. (by using Image icon of the editor)

Comment: Sorry, it tells me that I need 10 points of reputation to do it ;)

Comment: no problem. I did it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think I recall that ggplot2 used this color scheme by default for plots, if no color aesthetics was specified. However, later versions of ggplot now use a single color for simple frequencies (*without* grouping/colour aesthetics):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sjmisc)
data(efc)
ggplot(efc, aes(e42dep)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

That's why the image you posted has different colors, while now `sjp.frq` prints bars in one color only. Since you don't have a grouping aesthetics for simple frequency bars, you can't provide different colors for each geom / bar in `sjp.frq`. In this case, you have to find your own solution and add a group-aes, like:

```
ggplot(efc, aes(e42dep, fill = to_label(e42dep))) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  labs(y = NULL, x = get_label(efc$e42dep), fill = get_label(efc$e42dep)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:4), labels = get_labels(efc$e42dep))
```

[image]

However, to me it does not make much sense to give each bar a seperate color **and** provide axis labels. Using a legend instead of axis labels (drop axis labels) would work, but this makes the graph less intuitive, because you have to switch between legend and bars to find out which bar represents which category. For simple frequency plots, this is unnecessary complexity.